# DokuWiki Usage Link concept

Tags: php, documentation, wiki, dokuwiki

Okay so I don't know what this would be called, if something to support the idea exists or if it would be 100% custom / manual.

I've setup an internal wiki for documentation purposes using DokuWiki.

Lets say that we have server A and B each with their own pages.  And programs #1 - 4, also with their own pages (4).

Program 1 and 2 are reliant on server A.  Program 3 and 4 are reliant on server A and B.

Programs 1 and 2 would have links to server A in their documentation.

Programs 3 and 4 would have links to both Server A and B in their documentation.

Now... the goal would be for Server A's page to show a link to programs 1,2,3 and 4. Simply by knowing it was referenced in those pages.

1) Is there a name for this concept?

2) Is there a decent way of doing this with DokuWiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, backlinks would be the concept. There are plugins that can show backlink directly embedded into the page. Eg. https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:backlinks

A different way to achieve this (and more complex stuff) would be using the structured data plugin https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:data - you could have a data entry for the server on each program page and a data table or list at each server page.

Comment: perfect, backlinks are the answer.  Thank you Sir!